# Managing postgresql views without having to write migrations?

Tags: postgresql

The problems with SQL views is that every time I need to make a small change I need to create another migration. Being in a small startup, that's quite a hindrance to have to change something small to change the view.

Is it advisable to do the following

1. Drop and recreate view everytime I deploy my app;
2. This way, when I change something in the view, it will get updated in the database as soon as I deploy my app.

Comment: When you're a small startup you can do whatever you want if it does not break production and is comfortable for you.

Comment: what migration are you doing? What do you change? are you talking about postresql view or view layer?

Comment: @Mladen Uzelac: the question is pretty clear. If you cannot get what it's about - please make your own research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is just another type of migration that get reversed on deploy. This may make sense for your business needs, and if you get blocked by this technique, you can always fall back to the regular migration system.

The best way to implement such a system in PostgreSQL is to create a schema that you drop on deploy. This way you don't have to create all the `DROP VIEW ...` commands, just `DROP SCHEMA` and everything in there will be deleted. Then you can run you procedure to rebuild it.

Example deploy script to execute on deploy:

```
/* Drop and rebuild the schema */

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS view_schema;

CREATE VIEW view_schema.my_users AS (SELECT * FROM users);
CREATE VIEW view_schema.my_products AS (SELECT * FROM products);
....
```

Comment: This is actually really awesome advice and far better than what I have thought of. Could you elaborate on how this works. So I would create another schema, (e.g. view_schema); And the view schema will get dropped / rebuilt everytime I deploy?

Comment: Exactly, I added an example script to run on deploy.

Comment: I use this technique on several project for various purposes. It is safe as long as there is nothing that reference something into your schema. (like a foreign key that points to a table in the schema)

Comment: This is actually an awesome, and super practical advise. Thank you so much for your help; (I think you should write a blog post about this technique! :) )